# Eslint airbnb default with arrow functions in js

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm trying to use eslint with the preset style airBnB but I want to use arrow functions instead of normal functions. When I try to add anything to my .eslintrc.js files rules my vscode doesn't display the errors anymore. How can I fix this.

My .eslintrc.js is as following

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'airbnb',
  ],
  overrides: [
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
  ],
  rules: {
    allowArrorFunctions: true
  },
};
```

and package.json is the following:

```
{
  "name": "solita-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.2.3",
    "cypress-real-events": "^1.7.6",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.13.2",
    "jquery-ui-bundle": "^1.12.1-migrate",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!axios)/\"",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "cypress": "^12.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: `allowArrorFunctions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an extra rule to use arrow functions in your code if you have the correct parser options, so you could just remove the `rules` section from your .eslintrc.js config.

If you mean to use the rule [`func-style`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/func-style) with the option `allowArrowFunctions`, then the `rules` section in .eslintrc.js should look like this:

```json
  rules: {
    'func-style': ['error', 'declaration', { allowArrowFunctions: true }],
  }
```

Note that any incorrect setting in .eslintrc.js (like trying to configure a non-existing rule) will invalidate the whole configuration. Probably that's the reason why VSCode stops reporting linting problems.